# Meshlab increase point size

Tags: visualization, point-clouds, meshlab

How can I increase the point size in Meshlab for point clouds? I found how I can show / hide specific PCs, but I do not see where to change their display properties : size, color, symbol ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Meshlab 1.3, you have to do 3 steps:

- `View`->`Show Layers Dialog` to enable the panel at the right.
- `Render`->`Show Vertex Dots`,  to show the vertices as small circles.
- There is a `Dot size` field in the Layer Dialog that let you change the size of the circles.

[image: MeshLab 1.3.2]

If you are using Meshlab-2016 or later, it is even easier...

- Click on the tab of vertex and choose the option `Dot Decorator` (1)
- Change the size of dots with the `Point Size` Bar (2)

[image: Dot decorator]

Comment: I have 1.3 running. Turns out though that when you scale the points, their color will be reset to white. Where can I select the color in the ui? We call Meshlab out of a script.

Answer (score 2):

In MeshLab, you can just use `Alt + mouse wheel` to control point size.

Or you can find the point size setting in:
`Tools`->`Options`->`MeshLab::Appearance::pointSize`.